# Relative network path in a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, relative-path

I need to run a .bat file in a network path (UNC path).

At the beginning, my bat file was something like this

```
cd subfolder
some file operations
```

When I tested it on my local computer, it worked, but when I move the file to a network directory, I have:

```
'\\ComputerName\SharedFolder\Resource' is an invalid current directory path. UNC paths are not supported.
Defaulting to Windows directory.
C:\Windows
```

I tried to use `pushd` command, but it didn't help:

```
pushd subfolder
some file operations
```

```
'\\ComputerName\SharedFolder\Resource' is an invalid current directory path. UNC paths are not supported.
Defaulting to Windows directory.
C:\Windows>pushd subfolder
No such directory.
```

I can of course write something like this

```
pushd \\ComputerName\SharedFolder\Resource\subfolder
```

but I want to use the same .bat file in several folders, so I want to use a relative path. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, since you obviously know how to use pushd, but if you want to switch to a subfolder of the folder that contains your batch file, you can use `pushd %~dp0\subfolder`

Comment: Joe, yes `pushd %~dp0` is exactly what I was looking for :). Please remove your comment and write this as an answer.

Comment: w0xx0m has already added this to his answer, I suggest you accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `pushd` can be used to switch to an UNC path, so first use `pushd` to the path of the batch file, then `cd subfolder`:

```
pushd %~dp0
cd subfolder
some file operations
```